# Apparmor deny create operation

Tags: apparmor

I have a problem with IPSec. After debugging, I found this message in `dmesg`:

```
apparmor=“DENIED” operation=“create” profile=“/usr/lib/ipsec/charon” ..... requested_mask=“create” denied_mask=“create”
```

I tried to edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.ipsec.charon`, and give `/usr/lib/ipsec/charon` Permession: `rwmix`
But the problem still there. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set charon to complain mode.

Do `sudo aa-status` to see if `/usr/lib/ipsec/charon` is in enforce mode. Set it to complain by doing
`sudo aa-complain /usr/lib/ipsec/charon`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I check charon status, and it in enforce mode. I tried to make it in complain using aa-complain, but aa-complain in “apparmor-utils” which not installed in my device. And I don’t have any access to the internet in that device to install it via apt. So does there any another way to make profile in complain mode without needed to connect to the internet? Thanks again.

Comment: @PostNerdism Make a backup copy of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.ipsec.charon` Edit your `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.ipsec.charon` file with your favorite editor. In this file, you should see one of the first lines that says `profile /usr/lib/ipsec/charon` or something similar. After the `charon` part, add a flag, so it looks like `profile /usr/lib/ipsec/charon flags=(complain) {`, then restart apparmor.

Comment: Thanks. It works in complain mode now. But that doesn't affect the problem. As I read about complain mode, it not enforce any rule to the profile. And as I know, that mean all operations that the software can do, but still the problem there.